# Work with KML files Swift Application

Tags: ios, swift, maps, kml

I am working on a interesting project, this project allow to visualise some information (light pollution, cloud info, etc..) from KML/KMZ files on Maps or Google Maps. I would like to restitute this information with an iOS Application using Swift programming language.
I would like to know if it is possible to do this with iOS.

Thank you very much,

YM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that is iOS, Apple has provided a Demo for KML Parser, here is the link [KML Parser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KMLViewer/Listings/Classes_KMLParser_m.html).

Though the project is in Objective-C, you can import it with a Bridging Header so that you can use it from Swift.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: @Rajat can i do same by using google map ios sdk? please give me suggestion. here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262736/how-to-load-kml-file-into-google-maps-ios-sdk?noredirect=1#comment69726620_41262736

Answer (score 6):

**Step 1:**

Download apple's sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/KMLViewer/Listings/Classes_KMLParser_m.html).

**Step 2:**

Bridge KMLParser.m and KMLParser.h files from Apple's sample code to your project ( you can just drag it to your project ) If you never done it before, you can find a simple tutorial [here](https://www.ios-blog.com/tutorials/objective-c/how-to-use-objective-c-classes-in-swift/).

**Step 3:**

Add your KML File to your project in Xcode.

**Step 4:**

Example to parsing a polygon from KML file to MKMap:

[image]

Comment: This is WAY better than trying to stash a ton of KML coordinates into plists, etc, as is the case with some MapKit tutorials. Interesting to note is, assuming you have a large kml file with multiple `Placemarks`, `kmlParseMngr.overlays` is an `NSArray` of `MKPolylines`, so if you wanted to draw routes on a map, you can just iterate through it, cast each item as an `MKOverlay` and add to your mapview.